# How to join multiple tables and printing the result for same id which are populating more than one in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE details_1 (
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_details_1_e_id PRIMARY KEY ( e_id )
);

insert into details_1 values(11,'A');


CREATE TABLE ques_ans (
    ques_ans_id  NUMBER(10),
    ref_ques_id  NUMBER(10),
    ref_ans_id   NUMBER(10),
    e_id         NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_ques_ans PRIMARY KEY ( ques_ans_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ques_ans FOREIGN KEY ( e_id )
        REFERENCES details_1 ( e_id ),
        constraint fk_ques_and_ques_id foreign key(ref_ques_id)
        references ques_ref (ques_id)
);

insert into ques_ans values(1,3,1,11);
insert into ques_ans values(2,2,2,11);
insert into ques_ans values(3,4,1,11);

CREATE TABLE ques_ref (
    ques_id     NUMBER(10),
    code        VARCHAR2(50),
    code_label  VARCHAR2(100),
    constraint pk_ques_ref primary key(ques_id)
);

insert into ques_ref values(3,'changes_exist','Any known changes');
insert into ques_ref values(2,'E_Clubbed','E_id clubbed with other');
insert into ques_ref values(4,'E_impacted','E impacted by other');

CREATE TABLE ans_ref (
    ref_ans_id  NUMBER(10),
    code        VARCHAR2(10),
    code_value  VARCHAR2(30)
);

insert into ans_ref values(1,'R_Yes','Yes');
insert into ans_ref values(2,'R_No','No');
```

The problem facing in joining the tables :

Table ques_ans has ref_ques_id column that is being populated from ques_ref table.
So, If ref_ques_id = 3 and ref_ans_id = 1 then it should display 'Yes' i.e populating from ans_ref table. Likewise for ref_ques_id = 2 then it should display 'No' and same for ref_ques_id = 4.

My Attempt :

```
select d.e_id, qa.ref_ques_id,
ar.code_value

from details_1 d
join ques_ans qa on(d.e_id = qa.e_id)
join ans_ref ar on(ar.ref_ans_id = qa.ref_ans_id) ;
```

In my attempt, I am getting 3 rows but ideally expected output should be like attached in the screenshot.

[image: Expected Output]

Columne e_id : Coming from details_1 table

Column Changes_exist: Validation in the ques_ans table ref_ques_id column and based on the ref_ans_id printing Yes or no.

Column E_clubbed: Validation in the ques_ans table ref_ques_id column and based on the ref_ans_id printing Yes or no.

Column E_Impacted: Validation in the ques_ans table ref_ques_id column and based on the ref_ans_id printing Yes or no.

The output should be like the attached screenshot but I got stuck that how this can be printed in a single row

Tool: SQL Developer
Version: 20.4

Comment: You want to transform rows to columns - this can be done using the ```PIVOT``` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you wrote almost does it; there's another join missing (with `ques_ref`) so that you'd extract code name, but that still doesn't "fix" it because - as far as I can tell - there's no way to do it "dynamically" within SQL. What we *usually* do is to *pivot* data. One option is to use an aggregate function (`max` in this example) along with `case` expression, and to literally *name* every column (using code name you've previously extracted, but just to be of some help while writing column's alias).

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select d.e_id, qa.ref_ques_id, qr.code, ar.code_value
  3     from details_1 d
  4     join ques_ans qa on d.e_id = qa.e_id
  5     join ans_ref ar on ar.ref_ans_id = qa.ref_ans_id
  6     join ques_ref qr on qr.ques_id = qa.ref_ques_id
  7    )
  8  select e_id,
  9    max(case when ref_ques_id = 3 then code_value end) changes_exist,
 10    max(case when ref_ques_id = 2 then code_value end) e_clubbed,
 11    max(case when ref_ques_id = 4 then code_value end) e_impacted
 12  from temp
 13  group by e_id;

      E_ID CHANGES_EXIST   E_CLUBBED       E_IMPACTED
---------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
        11 Yes             No              Yes

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why we are using max function and what does it mean by pivoting the data?

Comment: You're welcome. Aggregation is used create only one row; try to run that code without it (and remove GROUP BY) - you'll get 3 rows with only 3 values, while the rest is empty (NULL). "Pivoting" means to "transform" layout from rows to columns.